# Easiest way to port GAE scalability into open source framework

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, bigtable

Say I want to make a java webapp using open source framework such as Spring Framework, and want to make it easily scalable (like Google App engine).

What options do I have (other than running it in GAE) ?

1. Which mvc-framework, db-persistence framework would you choose?
2. With database as a bottleneck, is there a way to mimic how BigTable behaves in the Java Webapp world ?

Answer (score 4):

[AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) is a GAE compatible framework. Code written for GAE should work on appscale.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **Java-based BigTable implementation**, take a look at [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) and it's sub-project [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/).

If **Java is not a requirement** (it's a server after all), then you can also **take a look at [hypertable](http://www.hypertable.org/)**.

Comment: Hadoop is mostly used with offline processing? I haven't heard anyone using it for online processing.

Comment: Well, you asked for BigTable, I gave you BigTable. :-P More specifically, have a look at Hadoop sub-project HBase: http://hbase.apache.org/ - this gives you "random, realtime read/write access to your Big Data".

Comment: ok thanks. I suppose it can be used for realtime read/write access.